# How can i show the data in collection laravel as a object?

Tags: php, json, laravel, api, collections

I have some problems with the collection of laravel. I have written the API and its shows like that:

```
[
  [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Zel",
        "age": 43
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "ZE",
        "age": 4
    }
  ]
]
```

I want to remove [] to show the data like:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Zel",
        "age": 43
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "ZE",
        "age": 4
    }
]
```

I have tried many solutions I found on the internet but no one working so does anyone know how to show the data as an example help me pls!!!

Comment: This should help - https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#method-flatten

Comment: Share your controller code if possible it’s mostly occur when usign response([$data],200) instead of response($data,200)

Comment: If you are confused about this, you will have to start with basics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
$collection = $collection->flatten() ;
```

take a look at the [Official documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#method-flatten)